# Grivdview search not working properly flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a gridview,i have implemented search,search is working fine,but the viewing of search item is not shows properly,

Before search

[image]

This how my gridview show after searching a item

[image]

**Code**

```
SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
              childAspectRatio: 6 / 5,
              // crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              SubCategoryModel data = sub_category_model[index];
              if (searchController.text.isEmpty) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 2,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100.0,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  imageUrl: Urls.BASE_IMAGE_URL +
                                      data.image.toString(),
                                  placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              data.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 13),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => OnlinecartSubitems(data.id.toString(),Category_Name),
                        ),
                      );
                  },
                );
              } else if (data.name.contains(searchController.text) ||
                  data.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchController.text) ||
                  data.name.toUpperCase().contains(searchController.text)) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 2,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100.0,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  imageUrl: Urls.BASE_IMAGE_URL +
                                      data.image.toString(),
                                  placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              data.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 13),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
               
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => OnlinecartSubitems(data.id.toString(),Category_Name),
                        ),
                      );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
            childCount: sub_category_model.length,
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Instead of your multiple condition to check if the name and the searchText match you could do this: `data.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchController.text.toLowerCase())`

Comment: I tried that,still same result@quoci

Comment: Yeah it won't change anything. It just better to read this line.

Comment: Where do you filter your items?

Comment: I am just searching within view,for listview there is no problem@quoci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with help of Benedict and Farhan Syah thanks for the idea and some codes

**Initialize variables**

```
//Search controller for textfield

TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

//For show list data first

List<SubCategoryModel> sub_category_model = [];

//for searchresult list 

List<SubCategoryModel> _searchResult = [];
```

**View**

```
_searchResult.length != 0 ||searchController.text.isNotEmpty?SliverGrid(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                        childAspectRatio: 6 / 5,
                        // crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 0),
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        SubCategoryModel data = _searchResult[index];

                        return GestureDetector(
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 2,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 0,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100.0,
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                          imageUrl: Urls.BASE_IMAGE_URL +
                                              data.image.toString(),
                                          placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                              child:
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                              Icon(Icons.error),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 0,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      data.name,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 13),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                        
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      childCount: _searchResult.length,
                    ),
                  ):SliverGrid(//use same code above with **sub_category_model.length**)
```

**Search widget**

```
  Widget _SearchText() {
    return Container(
      width: 360,
      height: 65,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: new Card(
          elevation: 8,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.5),
                hintText: 'Search by Name',
                suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      searchController.clear();
                      _searchResult.clear();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.cancel_rounded,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(34, 83, 148, 1))),
                prefixIcon:
                    Icon(Icons.search, color: Color.fromRGBO(34, 83, 148, 1)),
                border: InputBorder.none),
            onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
            controller: searchController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Onchanged function for searching through list**

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    //clear search data before typing
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }
    //use searchcontroller text and loop through list of api data and add the result to _searchResult

    sub_category_model.forEach((searchValue) {
      if (searchValue.name.toLowerCase().contains(text))
        _searchResult.add(searchValue);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a new list each time the search matches an item. Then, build a New GridView object based on the newly created list. Whenever your TextView is empty, you return the original list.

For Instance

```
//Create Search List
List<Object> searchList = [];

//Check if SearchTextView is empty or not with a ternary Operator
controller.text.isEmpty?

//Build your GridView based on the Original List
GridView.count(
   ...
   itemCount: mainList.length,
   ...
) //Replace with you SliverGrid

//Build your GridView based on the Search List
: GridView.count(
   ...
   itemCount: searchList.length
   ...
),//Replace with you SliverGrid
```

You can **Replace** my **GridView** with your **SilverGrid** widget.

The full Code (*Spoiler alert: Very long*):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Search TextField Controller
  final _searchController = TextEditingController();
  
  List<Fruit> mainList = [
    Fruit(name: 'Apple', imageUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/102104/pexels-photo-102104.jpeg'),
    Fruit(name: 'Banana', imageUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5945848/pexels-photo-5945848.jpeg'),
    Fruit(name: 'Pineapple', imageUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1071878/pexels-photo-1071878.jpeg'),
    Fruit(name: 'Mango', imageUrl: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/918643/pexels-photo-918643.jpeg'),
  ];
  List<Fruit> searchList = [];
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column( 
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 60.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _searchController,
              onChanged: (text){
                final String queryString = _searchController.text;
                setState((){
                  if(queryString.isNotEmpty){
                    
                    for(final fruit in mainList){
                      if(fruit.name.contains(queryString)){
                        searchList.add(fruit);
                      } else{
                        searchList.remove(fruit);
                      }
                    }
                  }else{
                    searchList.clear();
                  }
                });
              }
            ),
          ),
          
          Expanded(
            child: _searchController.text.isEmpty
            ? GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: mainList.map((fruit)=> CardWidget(fruit: fruit)).toList(),
            )
            :GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: searchList.map((searchedFruit)=>CardWidget(fruit: searchedFruit)).toList()
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Create a Class to hold Fruit

```
class Fruit{
  final String imageUrl;
  final String name;
  
  Fruit({this.imageUrl, this.name});
}
```

Create widget to be built for each fruit object found in the `mainList`

```
//Card Widget
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  final Fruit fruit;
  
  CardWidget({this.fruit});
  
  @override
  _CardWidgetState createState()=> _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget>{
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 140.0,
      child: Column(
        children:[
          Image(image: NetworkImage(widget.fruit.imageUrl)),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Text(widget.fruit.name),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Try it and let see

Comment: I have seen some kind of idea,but i stuck how to integrate into my code@Benedict

Comment: Ok. I should give you a full implementation, right?

Comment: That will be really helpful or  redirect me to solutions,i have searched but nothing found @Benedict

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the full example implementation for you. Check and let me know.

Comment: I  tried your code but there is issue when i search apple it shows only pineapple also it shows duplicate data,but thanks for the heads up i have tried the logic and come up by changing few things and i have fixed the issue

Comment: At least you mark it as the right answer if it solved the initial question you asked.

Comment: I will mark it as useful,not right answer,because it have problem,if i search for banana it doesn't show also the above issue i told hour ago@B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235306/discussion-between-benedict-and-assassin).

Comment: Code is still have bugs ,Even after i pointed out what wrong in the code and what happens when i run the code you didn't even made effort to fix the code,if i accept your answer someone will come here look into your code and implement in their app,for beginners it is still need to work figure it out what wrong with it again.So that's why.. @Benedict

Comment: So fix the issue, the bugs, if search banana it doesn't show anything and if search for apple it still doesn't show apple it shows pineapple with multiple duplicate data,so make sure it works, so how would i mark this as a correct answer@Benedict

Answer (score 0):

You are returning Container() when the search condition doesn't match. Container itself will take a place of a widget, hence, it will be an item of the grids.

To test this, you can try putting something inside the container, such as:

```
Container(
 child: Text('This grid is not empty)
)
```

The problem with this, is if you have 12 items in the data, no matter your search result, it will still build 12 items (including the empty container)

To solve this, you need a better way to filter the data, such as using a list to filter, and then passing the list data to the grid builder.

The concept is like this:

Original list : 10 items

Newlist based on the search: 5 items

The grid builder will build the items based on the list provided.

Comment: if i use this also it happens only in gridview not in listview why is that,..? @Farhan Syah

Comment: it is because the container size.

In list view, empty container doesn't have any size, so it will not be seen.

in grid view, the container will have size, so it always occupy some space