# How do I add a search box in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this class name index which pushes some data from some web to a list. I just want to filter out the results by name for example. I am a newbie in flutter and it would be appreciated some help
you can see below how we fetch data from fetchUser>getBody>getCard
Inside getCard there is my "item['name']" that I would like to look up

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    //import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as nose;
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/pages/theme/color.dart';
    
    class IndexPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _IndexPageState createState() => _IndexPageState();
    }
    
    class _IndexPageState extends State<IndexPage> {
      List users = [];
      bool isLoading = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.fetchUser();
      }
    
      fetchUser() async {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1000";
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var items = json.decode(response.body)['results'];
          setState(() {
            users = items;
            isLoading = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            users = [];
            isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Usuarios'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: getBody());
      }
    
      Widget getBody() {
        if (users.contains(null) || users.length < 0 || isLoading) {
          return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red)));
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: users.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return getCard(users[index]);
            });
      }
    
      String searchString = "";
    
    
      Widget getCard(item) {
        var fullName = item['name']['title'] +
            " " +
            item['name']['first'] +
            " " +
            item['name']['last'];
        var email = item['email'];
        var profileUrl = item['picture']['large'];
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primary,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60 / 2),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage((profileUrl.toString())))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
            
                        Text(fullName.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Calibri')),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 11,
                        ),
                        Text(email, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10))
                      ])
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you search list of records using search bar go to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624790/13997210

Comment: could you indicate if I have to create a new class? How can I pass Item['name'] to that search bar?