# Search Filter on ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem about filtering the data that I get from the json response. I already put the service initialization in initSate instead of `future` in FutureBuilder but it's still not working. Maybe I miss something in the filter function?

initState :

```
  void initState() {
    doctorService = DoctorService();
    _doctorData = doctorService.getDoctors();
    super.initState();
  }
```

FutureBuilder:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Daftar Dokter"),),
        body:
          FutureBuilder<List<Doctor>>(
            future: _doctorData,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot);
                  return Center(
                    child: Text("Error"),
                  );
                }
                else if (snapshot.hasData){
                  doctors = snapshot.data;
                  tempDoctorData = List.from(doctors);
                  return _buildListView(tempDoctorData);
                }
                else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {  
              Navigator.push(
                  context, 
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext buildContext)=>FormAlbum())
              );
            },
          ),
      );
  }
```

And this is the filter function

```
 onItemChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      tempDoctorData = doctors.where((element) => element.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())).toList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you search data from list , that data comes from API And you will display it in Listview and you search it from search box so go through my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624790/13997210

Comment: if your data is shown multiple times (for example each time you type anything in search `TextField`) then use `StreamBuilder`, instead of `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil From my understanding of your code, we need to call API everytime we use the filter? Sorry if I'm wrong, I'm new to Flutter

Comment: No need to call API every time

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil thank you, it works now. Looks like my problem is because I save the list in the `build` function, so its always reloading everytime I call `setState`